# VPN tunnel between two routers is not working

Tags: networking, router, vpn, l2tp

I have two VPN routers (ER605). I have set up L2TP server on router 1 and I can connect to it from my phone and other devices. I want to connect router 2 to router 1 and route all my traffic through router 1.

I have done the following so far:

- Set up L2TP server on router 1.
- Set up L2TP client on router 2.

I can see that the tunnel works through diagnostics menu and tunnel list on router 2.

Screenshots from router 2:

[image: traceroute]
<sup>**traceroute**</sup>

[image: tunnel list]
<sup>**tunnel list**</sup>

What configuration should I do to route all of my traffic through this tunnel ?

Comment: The (too?) simple answer seems that if router 1 is the gateway of router 2, router 1 can remain the DHCP server and all devices can connect to it.